# How to fetch PFUser Object with all (recursive) children

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have the following structure:

My User Table has a field called `experienceArray`, which is just an Array of Pointers to another table called `experience`. Every `experience` object has got a Pointer to another table `Sport`. `Sport` is just a simple table containing a Title (String). I'm trying to show the title of each object in a tableview. Unfortunately I'm getting exceptions in my tableview delegate, where I'm assigning the title value to my tableview cell label.

```
var object : PFObject = self.chosenSports[indexPath.row]["sport"] as! PFObject
```

Here's what it says:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "title_en" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'`

The message absolutely makes sense to me - it doesn't get the most inner child objects, only their objectIds.

Here's what I do:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query!.includeKey("experienceArray")
query!.includeKey("experienceArray.Sport")
query!.includeKey("experienceArray.Sport.title_en")
query!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result: [AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    println("sports result: \(result)")
    var res = result as! NSArray
    var user = res[0]
    self.chosenSports = user["experienceArray"] as! NSMutableArray
    self.sportsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

How would I change my code to receive all the information contained within the PFUser Object and all their children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to fetch all the children with cloud code and just call the cloud function from the App. This was pretty straightforward and turned out to be the best solution, because now there's less code on each system (iOS and Android)

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Because i am having the same problem.

Comment: I wrote a Cloud Code function which returns all the elements with their children

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/UAmKTrss it's one of the two functions, I don't remember exactly right now but it's one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and tell me if it works:

```
PFUser.currentUser().fetchIfNeeded { user, error in
   if error == nil && user != nil {
          if let sports = user["experienceArray"] as? [PFObject] {
              let query = PFQuery(className: "Sport") // Change to correct name.
              query.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: sports.map { $0.objectId })
              query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in 
                     // TODO: Use results
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Of course since I don't know how you're saving stuff to iVars I included the code inside the block but you can simply assign it to an ivar. This should work.

**EDIT**: Changed code to make only 2 requests. Also note the code doesn't handle errors, but this should be easy to do.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. I haven't tried this out yet, but this solution will again do a lot of requests because of the `sport.fetchIfNeeded`, which is something I want to avoid :(

Comment: @gasparuff See edit. This only performs 2 queries saving a lot of time.

Comment: I would need to fetch an additional relation as well, called "Locations". Using your approach this would be another additional request. Shouldn't it be possible to write some cloud code and fetch everything using just 1 request by calling the cloud code?

Comment: Yeah you can write cloud code to do this too. That would have to be in Javascript though

Comment: How would I do that? Do I need to work with things like includeKey as well?

Comment: No just use the reduced fetches from the code above (converted to Javascript) inside a function (which takes the `PFUser`'s id as parameter and call that function from swift inside the app. Then return the results down only once. That way all the code is executed on the server itself.